# list background not changing in CSS in hover

Tags: html, css

hover on first element of list changes the whole background to some other colour. but hover other element except first changes background also but some portion of background is left  unchanged there as you can see in picture.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="add_friend">
    <ul id="frnd_bar_2">
        <li>Add To Friends</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Photos</li>
        <li>Friends</li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#frnd_bar_2{
      position:relative;
      list-style: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-left: 2px solid grey;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
}
#frnd_bar_2 li{
     cursor:pointer;
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     border-right: 2px solid grey;
     text-align:center;
     margin: 0px auto;
     padding: 5px;
     padding-left: 30px;
     padding-right: 30px;
     font: 20px sans-serif ;
}
#frnd_bar_2 li:hover {
     background: #aaa;
     margin: 0px auto;
}
#add_friend{
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background:#efefef;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

is there any problem in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be because of whitespace in HTML code. Either add `font-size: 0` to `#frnd_bar_2` or put all **li**'s into one line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm highlighting the key problem:

You should use `display: inline-block` to your `#frnd_bar_2 li` bu not to `#frnd_bar_2`

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/7P6V3/) other things you can change as per your needs

Okay just use `display: table-cell;` in your #frnd_bar_2 li and remove display from #frnd_bar_2
[demo updated](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/7P6V3/1/)

Comment: i appreciate your answer but your code breaks list elements but i want them to look like as the are in picture

Comment: You can remove the padding left and right applied in #frnd_bar_2 li